# How to get fiber.Ctx inside Gorm's AfterCreate() hook

Tags: go, hook, go-gorm, go-fiber

I need to call some methods of fiber context like `MultipartForm()` and `SaveFile()` inside Gorm's `AfterCreate()` hook, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a field in the struct to hold `fiber.Ctx` in. Then call methods on this in AfterCreate hook.

```
type User struct {
  c *fiber.Ctx
  <Other fields>
}

func (user *User) AfterCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    // user.c.MultipartForm()/ SaveFile()
    return nil
}
```